# Is it possible to add security to specific Node-RED tab in dashboard?

Tags: node-red

I would like to have some functions for handling my system on a specific Tab in my Dashboard that I would like to protect.
Is there a way to Password protect only a specific Tab in the Dashboard?

Comment: How is this question "too broad" to be voted to "Close"? Please note I am not questioning the "close" votes, just trying to understand why this question is not a good (or good enough) one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only protect the whole dashboard with basic auth

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that answer... I will dig through it a bit and see if I can possibly add something to the expressJS layer to accomplish something.